# Yii update transaction in loop

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I try update records in loop, I use for that transactions.

```
protected function getNeedsToBeConfirmedTransactions($offset)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->limit = 100;
    $criteria->offset = $offset;
    $this->offset += 100;
    return Transaction::model()->findAll($criteria);
}

$mysqlTransaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){

    $tr = $this->getNeedsToBeConfirmedTransactions($this->offset);

    //Here in foreach I;m updating transaction and execute 
    //$transaction->save();

}

$mysqlTransaction->commit();
```

I have 4000 record, but in 10 iteretion I get NOTHING, because Yii locking my record and i can't select.

What to do with this ? I surely must use transaction select, because I can't select all without limit, that can be very slow.

Comment: It's not so clear to me from that code, but anyway, what does the catch give you as error?

Comment: @Masiorama nothing, continue loop

Comment: can you post the actual code? so far it's obv partial/broken, so it's not possibile to take a good guess. it's not clear to me how you are approaching the transactions (try - catch)